# SQL Query Error to get the eligible students from table

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I would like to get results for

1. `subject` should be PHY or CHE and `last_mark` should be grater than 74
2. With Condition 1, if that fails then `total_gpa` should be grater than 2.4125
3. Anyway `total_gpa` should grater than 1.5000 for all

I used the query as follows,

```
SELECT person_id,name,total_gpa,status 
FROM data_table 
WHERE subject='PHY' | 'CHE' 
   AND last_mark>74 OR total_gpa >2.4125 OR total_gpa > 1.5000
```

Here I know that my query is totally wrong, `total_gpa >2.4125 OR total_gpa > 1.5000` is haven't meaning. But i could not write a query to solve my problem, Anybody please help me?

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. I have removed [tag:php] because it has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are Requesting some conditions in your query to select rows.

**1. Condition 1**

`subject` should be PHY or CHE and `last_mark` should be grater than 74. So the Query want to be like this

```
(subject='PHY' OR subject='CHE') AND last_mark > 74
```

Because, You want `(TRUE OR FALSE) AND TRUE = 'TRUE'`  or `(FALSE OR TRUE) AND TRUE = 'TRUE'` . So that bracket is needed at that point.

**2. Condition 2**

With Condition 1, if that fails then `total_gpa` should be grater than 2.4125. So you are going to check whether `Condition 1 OR Condition 2`. So the Query want to be like this

```
((subject='PHY' OR subject='CHE') AND last_mark > 74) OR total_gpa > 2.4125
```

**3. Condition 3**

Anyway `total_gpa` should grater than 1.5000 for all. So you are checking to all students who should has the `total_gpa > 1.5000` . So the Query want to be like `(ANY CONDITION) AND total_gpa > 1.5000`.

```
(((subject='PHY' OR subject='CHE') AND last_mark > 74) OR total_gpa > 2.4125) AND total_gpa > 1.5000
```

So the Final Query want to be like this following one,

```
SELECT person_id,name,total_gpa,status
FROM data_table 
WHERE 
(((subject='PHY' OR subject='CHE') AND last_mark > 74) OR total_gpa > 2.4125) 
AND total_gpa > 1.5000
```

Comment: Perfect description, Thank you for the effort. I got understand

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap things in parentheses:

```
SELECT person_id,name,total_gpa,status 
FROM data_table 
WHERE total_gpa > 1.5000 AND (((subject='PHY'  OR subject = 'CHE') 
AND last_mark>74) OR total_gpa >2.4125)
```